# 400 responses switch to 200 if I change the wifi, despite the use of proxy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping some 26,000 items in a web site from its API via Scrapy. I use a rotating proxy. When I run the spider it starts working well for a while. But then the rate of 400 responses increases up to a point that almost 95% of are refused.

When I switch from my current Wi-Fi and connect to another Wi-Fi, for example my phone's hotspot, the rate of 200 responses peak again to be ultimately slowed down again. I set the retry times to 50 which extremely prolongs the scraping process which takes up to 16 hours. I think there must be a way to reduce these negative responses.

So, the question is, despite the fact that I use a proxy, why would changing the connected Wi-Fi station increases my rates of 200 responses?

Thank you

Comment: It changes your network and IP address. The API is rate-limiting you because of the huge number of requests you're sending in a short period of time. Read through the API's docs or contact the admin to see if there is a way you can access the data more quickly (likely through an account, possibly paid). Otherwise, you'll just need to find the minimum time you need to wait between requests, and deal with it.

Comment: But I'm connecting to web site via a proxy. How can it spot my ip so that it can apply rate-limit to me?

Comment: Unless they tell you, there's no way to know how any particular site is deciding that "you" have made too many requests.  The site may have experienced abusive requests coming from hotspots from the same phone carrier that you have.  They may have decided to more strictly limit requests coming from a particular range of IPs, as the abusive connections always come from IPs in that range.  If your carrier assigns you an IP in that same range, you may suffer from the same limitations despite having done nothing yourself to cause it.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same proxy when you switch from wifi to hot spot? I'm not sure how your particular rotating proxy works, but you had to get a new connection when you made the switch and that may automatically roll your proxy IP address.

Comment: Excuse me Max how did you come to the conclusion that I am being abusive?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the proxy software you are using, it may be setting the HTTP headers `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-IP`, which can be used to see your IP even if you are using a proxy. Chaning your wifi, however, changes really device's IP, and therefore the IP in `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-IP`. I don't know what proxy you are using, but check if there are any options or modules to spoof/unset the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Real-IP` headers.